# SQL Calculated field selected values

Tags: sql

I have a SQL View with columns `IDX, DATE, SIGNAL, VALUE`
We have `SIGNAL1 to SIGNAL10`
What I want is that on Daily basis a computed column which is calculated as follows:

```
Compval= SIGNAL7*SIGNAL8-SIGNAL9
```

Other columns retain the original values

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can create another view or just add this column to your view:

```
create view v_view as
    select v.*, (SIGNAL7*SIGNAL8-SIGNAL9) as CompVal
    from first_view v;
```

Answer (score 0):

In MS SQL server you can add computed column like below

```
    ALTER table TableA ADD compVal AS SIGNAL7*SIGNAL8-SIGNAL9
```

Comment: . . The question is specifically about a view and not a table.  Does this work in any database for a view?

Comment: Hi I am getting error : Incorrect Syntax near keyword: add

Comment: As I vave mentioned I need to compute A column based on VALUE of certain signal for example CompVal= ValueOfSignal7* valueOfSignal8-ValueOfSignal9. So Directly writing SIGNAL7*SIGNAL8-SIGNAL9 is not goint to help as these represent Signal names not value

Comment: which version of sql? i am assuming these are columns so we can use them like that